# Python Email Parsing Issue

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, gmail, smtplib

so I'm trying to write a script in python that logs into my gmail account and then tells me, soon in a GUI, what the message is. I will do a bit more stuff to the code later on to make it a bit program a bit more useful but right now I'm stuck on just being able to parse the raw information that I am getting. Here is my code:

```
#Read Email Script
import imaplib
import email

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('username@gmail.com', 'passwordgoeshere')
mail.list()
mail.select("INBOX") # connect to inbox.


result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")

ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()
latest_email_id = id_list[-1]

result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, '(RFC822)')

raw_email = data[0][1]

email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)

print (email_message['Subject'])
```

Now this is basically supposed to try and read out the subject of the latest email that was delivered to my inbox. However I get the following error message in the console:

```
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dhruvin Desai/Documents/Python/script.py", line 21, in <module>
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\email\__init__.py", line 40, in message_from_string
    return Parser(*args, **kws).parsestr(s)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\email\parser.py", line 69, in parsestr
    return self.parse(StringIO(text), headersonly=headersonly)
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
>>>
```

I don't know why this is coming up but since its telling me that the value of `email_message` needs to be in string format, I tried this:

```
email_message = email.message_from_string(str(raw_email))
```

But the result after running the entire script with that change always, no matter what, resulted in the console saying `None`

I don't know what to do, please help.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because you are using Python3, [instead of using](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_string):

```
email.message_from_string(raw_email)
```

[use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_bytes):

```
email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)
```

Comment: Such a small change made a huge difference. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @bloodstorm17 There's one thing i forgot to mention. The content got from Gmail is encoded with base64, you need to decode it to get the real subject

Comment: Whoever reading this answer, be aware of this Gmail API documentation: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get -- This answer helped me get over this bump. I requested Gmail API team to change this documentation.